# SQL How would I group records based on conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, having

I'm trying to find any customers with a total of at least 4 accounts with at least 1 account that has been open in the last 6 months.

So far I'm able to get the customer and total accounts, but I'm not sure how to add a column for the number of new accounts open in the last 6 months.

```
SELECT CustomerID
       ,COUNT(AccountID) as 'Total Accounts'
FROM Customer
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(AccountID) >= 3`
```

Here are my tables:

[image: Customer]

and

[image: Accounts]

And here is what my **final result** should look like. so far I have CustomerID and Total Accounts.

```
CustomerID | Total Accounts | New Accounts |
-----------+----------------+------------- +
    Ben    |       3        |      1       |
```

EDIT: The program I'll be importing this query in doesn't allow case statements.

Comment: You don't really need the number of accounts opened in the last 6 months do you? Sounds like you just need the date of the last account opened. i.e. the `MAX` date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can left join the new accounts. Include the filter for `startdate` in the join condition. For accounts, that don't satisfy that condition no record from `account` is joined. So the account ID is null for them and won't get counted.

```
SELECT c.customerid,
       count(c.accountid) "Total Accounts",
       count(a.accountid) "New Accounts"
       FROM customer c
            LEFT JOIN account a
                      ON a.accountid = c.accountid
                         AND a.startdate >= dateadd(month, -6, getdate())
       GROUP BY c.customerid
       HAVING count(c.accountid) >= 4
              AND count(a.accountid) >= 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

`Count`, like most aggregate functions, ignores `null`s. I'd use this property by joining the two tables and using a `case` expression to return only the new accounts:

```
SELECT   CustomerId, 
         COUNT(*) AS TotalAccounts,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, StartDate, GETDATE()) <= 6 THEN 1 END) 
           AS NewAccounts
FROM     Customer c
JOIN     Accounts a ON c.AccountId = a.AccountId
GROUP BY CustomerId
HAVING   COUNT(*) >= 4 AND
         COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, StartDate, GETDATE()) <= 6 THEN 1 END) > 0
```

Comment: some platforms will give a warning because of the nulls

Comment: I can't use case statements. Is there a way I can do this without it?

Comment: @user10301497 why can't you?

Comment: @Mureinik The program I import the query into doesn't allow case statements for some reason.

Comment: @Mureinik Also I think I would need a sub query because TotalAccounts and NewAccounts both would have 4 with your query. I would need 3 in Total Accounts and 1 in new Accounts.

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you the total account count and the number that is new.

```
SELECT C.CustomerID,
       COUNT(C.AccountID) as Total_Acc,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEADD(MONTH,-6,GETDATE()) <= A.StarDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as New_Acct
FROM Customer C
LEFT JOIN Account A ON C.AccountID = A.AccountID
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

You can then use that in a sub-query to find what you want

eg

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT C.CustomerID,
       COUNT(C.AccountID) as Total_Acc,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEADD(MONTH,-6,GETDATE()) <= A.StarDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as New_Acct
  FROM Customer C
  LEFT JOIN Account A ON C.AccountID = A.AccountID
  GROUP BY CustomerID
) SUB
WHERE Total_Acc >= 4 and New_Acct >= 1
```

Comment: I can't use case statements. Is there a way I can do this without it?

Comment: @user10301497 why can't you use case statements?

Comment: @user10301497 you can but it is twice or three times as long to run.

Comment: The program I import the query into doesn't allow case statements for some reason.

Comment: What program is that @user10301497

Answer (score 1):

> The program I'll be importing this query in doesn't allow case
>   statements.

For your stated goal of finding customers with at least 4 accounts and at least 1 account that has been opened in the last 6 months you don't need the count of recent accounts anyway. It is sufficient to get the latest account date opened and see if that was in the last 6 months.

```
SELECT c.CustomerId
FROM   Customer c
       JOIN Accounts a
         ON c.AccountId = a.AccountId
GROUP  BY c.CustomerId
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4
       AND MAX(a.StartDate) >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
```